# How exactly is the electric potential of a wire related to the underlying particles?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage, conductors

Suppose that the positive side of battery is connected to a wire, so that the electric potential of the wire converges to that of the battery.

My question is: suppose that we say that wire with zero charge has zero voltage, and one particular wire has $50\ \text{Volts}$. What exactly does that say about the electric potential field of that wire, at the micro level?

- That the integral of the electric potential field over the volume of the wire is $50\ \text{Volts per m}^3$?
- That the amount of protons and electrons have a certain ratio?
- Something else? Both?

EDIT: To be clear, my question is about what this implies about the **microscopic** state of the wire. I know what it implies about the macroscopic properties of the electric circuit.

Comment: Yes, it is the integral of the electric potential field over the crossection of the wire

Answer (score 2):

Discussing microscopic properties of wires within a context of circuit theory is not a good idea: the circuit theory is based on the *lumped elements description*, reducing the circuit to point-like resistances, inductances, and capacitors connected by *ideal* wires. The wires are there only to show the connections.

Microscopically there are many levels on which one can describe the structure of a material with a potential difference applied to its sides. The description that one often encounters in electronics textbooks to treat semiconductor structures (transistors, diodes, solar cells, etc.) assumes that the potential varies slowly
throughout the material (compared to microscopic parameters such as Fermi wavelength or mean free path). In this case one replaces the chemical potential in the Fermi-Dirac distribution by $\mu - e\varphi(z)$, so that the electron concentration is given by
$$n(z) = \int dE \frac{D(E)}{1+e^{\beta\left[E-\mu - e\varphi(z)\right]}}\approx
\int dE D(E)e^{-\beta\left[E-\mu - e\varphi(z)\right]}.
$$
This is *the material equation* for the charge density, which then has to be solved self-consistently with the Poisson equation:
$$\partial_z^2\varphi(z) = -4\pi en(z),$$
and the boundary conditions for the potential at the end of the conductor:
$$\varphi(0) = 0, \varphi(L)=V.$$

**Remark**
In semiconductors one often uses the high-temperature approximation:
$$n(z) \approx \int dE D(E)e^{-\beta\left[E-\mu - e\varphi(z)\right]},$$
whereas in metals it is more appropriate to use the low-temperature formula:
$$n(z) = \int dE D(E)\Theta\left[\mu + e\varphi(z)-E\right].
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's what goes on in the micro-scale:

There are electrons in the wire, and they are moving randomly with some very low velocity. Now, the wire is connected to a battery. The battery changes the electric potential energy on the two ends of the wire. The arrangement now is such that one end has higher potential energy and one end has lower potential energy. In other words, there is now an energy difference between the two ends of the wire.

Okay, now back to the electrons: the change in potential energy across the wire, which we denote by $50V$, applies an electromagnetic force on the electrons. We call this the 'electro-motive force' or EMF. Due to this force (NOTE: The EMF is a no-contact force), the electrons start to move in a particular direction.

The electrons move very slowly, but their new motion causes some disturbances in the electric fields, and these disturbances move with very high speeds, causing what we call 'electricity'. This is a dumbed-down version, but for now, it will do.

That is why we need to create a potential difference in the wire: to get electricity. This is what happens on the microscopic level when we say that the wire has a potential difference. The electrons feel a force, and they start moving uniformly due to this force.

Comment: I understand all this, but I am looking for a quantitative description of the micro-scale state of the wire.

Comment: (note that even if there is no current, there can still be a voltage differential accross a wire)

Comment: If there is a potential difference across a wire then it must have a current,